# set-AzureStaticVNetIP Is not setting static IP on Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure

I am attempting to set the IP of a VM using the following script.  However it returns this mysterious error which I am unable to resolve.

```
$cloudSvcName = "My-SPService";
Test-AzureStaticVNetIP –VNetName My-SPNetwork –IPAddress 10.0.0.4
$dns = Get-AzureVM -Name "My-DNS" -ServiceName $cloudSvcName ;
stop-AzureVM -Name  $dns.Name -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Force;
set-AzureStaticVNetIP -VM $dns -IPAddress 10.0.0.4 | update-AzureVM;
```

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] update-AzureVM : BadRequest: The value for parameter 'SubnetNames' is null or empty.
[ERROR] At C:\Users\Tim\Source\Repos\Powershell Azure\AzurePowerShell\ScratchPad.ps1:12 char:104
[ERROR] + ... ess 10.0.0.4 | update-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName;
[ERROR] +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureVM], CloudException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.UpdateAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$sub = "PubSubnet";  #Set to whatever subnet you have set up

$cloudSvcName = "My-SPService";
Test-AzureStaticVNetIP –VNetName My-SPNetwork –IPAddress 10.0.0.4
$dns = Get-AzureVM -Name "My-DNS" -ServiceName $cloudSvcName ;
stop-AzureVM -Name  $dns.Name -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Force;

$dns | Set-AzureSubnet –SubnetNames $sub | set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress 10.0.0.4 | update-AzureVM;
```

Comment: This answer helped, but then I got "The virtual network name cannot be null or empty."

Comment: I am having the same issue.  After you fix "the virtual network name cannot be null...", you will get another error.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833662/how-to-use-public-static-ip-with-azure-vm

Answer (score -1):

So,

Currently Azure does not supports setting up the Internal IP address if you are using a Reserved IP address.

But you can assign a Static Internal IP address while creating a VM.

Meanwhile you can not edit a VM and add the Reserved IP address on the fly.

To sum up - You can not use Static Internal IP address with VNet and Reserved IP address together at a time in a VM.

Stuck up.