# How to use public static IP with Azure VM

Tags: azure, static-ip-address

After spending several hours of trying every relevant Azure Power Shell command to assign a virtual public IP to a Azure VM, I am back to square one.  It is amazing that such a basic function cannot be done in Azure.

First, I reserved a static IP.  Then create a vm.  Then tried set-azurestaticvnetip.  It complaint that subnetnames could not be null.  So I created a virtual network in Azure portal and created a subnet.  Then used set-azuresubnet -subnetnames subnet-1. Now it complaint that virtual network name could not be null.  Problem is that none of the commands in the sequence takes -vnetname as a parameter.

I then found that this parameter could be passed in new-azurevm.  So I deleted (what a nice workaround. i am glad I did not spend time configuring software in the vm) the VM and tried to create using this command. (image parameter is not specified in this command. I was entering that on prompt).

```
new-azurevmconfig -name myvm -instancesize Basic_A2|
add-azureprovisioningconfig -adminusername "myvmadmin" -windows -password "myvmP123"|
set-azuresubnet -subnetnames subnet-1 |
set-azurestaticvnetip -ipaddress 23.101.39.28 |
new-azurevm -servicename myvm -vnetname mynet –Location "East US" -waitforboot
```

Throws error-

```
new-azurevm : BadRequest : The static address 23.101.39.28 doesn't belong to the address space defined by the role's subnets.
```

What is wrong here?  Looks to me, these instructions are for assigning a private IP to VM.  It is so easy to assign a static IP to a VM created through Web Role (just put public IP name in the config file, thats it).  How do I assign a Public IP to a VM.  Microsoft documentation merely states that public IP can be used for a VM but did they think everybody would know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to create a regional vnet. This worked for me:

1) Get your current Network Config

```
 Get-AzureVNetConfig -ExportToFile "c:\temp\MyAzNets.netcfg"
```

2) Open the MyAzNets.netcfg and edit/(add?) a VirtualNetworkSite.  I think the key here is Location and not Affinity Group.  Your reserved IP/VM will need to be in the same.

You should have something like this:

```
<VirtualNetworkSites>
  <VirtualNetworkSite name="yourvnet" Location="West US">
    <AddressSpace>
      <AddressPrefix>192.168.50.0/24</AddressPrefix>
    </AddressSpace>
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="yoursubnet">
        <AddressPrefix>192.168.50.0/24</AddressPrefix>
      </Subnet>
    </Subnets>
  </VirtualNetworkSite>
</VirtualNetworkSites>
```

3) Send it back into Azure:

```
Set-AzureVNetConfig -ConfigurationPath "C:\temp\MyAzNets.netcfg"
```

4) Add/Get your IP in the same location as your vnet.

```
Get-AzureReservedIP / New-AzureReservedIP
```

5) Create your VM.

When creating or moving a VM make sure the cloud service doesn't exist. To move a VM just hit the capture button in the management portal and give it a friendly name then delete both the VM AND cloud service.

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "my-vm01" -InstanceSize Basic_A2 -ImageName "someimage" -Label "my-vm" | Set-AzureSubnet "**yoursubnet**" | Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort 3389 -Name 'RDP' -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 61030 | Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort 80 -Name 'HTTP' -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 80 | Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort 443 -Name 'HTTPS' -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 443| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "my-vm" -ReservedIPName "**reservedipname**" -Location "West US" -VNetName "**yourvnet**"
```

6) The IP should be assigned.  If you run Get-AzureReservedIP it should now show something like this:

```
ReservedIPName       : reservedipname
Address              : 127.0.0.1
Id                   : xxx
Label                :
Location             : West US
State                : Created
InUse                : True
ServiceName          : my-vm
DeploymentName       : my-vm
```

Comment: I already have a reservedIP. It starts from 23.100 (same Location as vnet location and every other location in my account).  I added this in netcfg.  Got this error  IP address prefix is not valid '23.100.0.0/24' on local site or virtual network with the name "mynet".  I noticed that you are reserving IP after setting config. How do you know your reserved ip will start with 192. ?

Comment: Your vnet IP addresses are private.  When you create your vnet subnets you should use range 10.* or 192.168.*. All your services assigned to this vnet will receive an IP out of this block.  When you map your reserved IP (23.100.*) to a service it basically just forwards to the private IP.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to dynamically assign a reserved IP to a VM (or Cloud Service Web Role) after the VM is created and without any tear down.  Works for me.  Just do this;

New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedIP –Location "East US"

Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP  -ServiceName MyVMName

First command reserves the IP.  Second command assigns it to the VM.  The assignment is immediate and the server will reboot

Comment: I also found the command Get-AzureRerservedIP useful to check the name of my reserved IP. I'd created it through the portal and the name I needed to use also included the resource group name. Also the VM needs to be running for you to set the association.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials with different options in the last two days, finally this worked:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "mysite" -InstanceSize Basic_A2  -Label "mysite" | Set-AzureSubnet "subnet-1" | add-azureprovisioningconfig -adminusername "myuser" -windows -password "mypwd"|  Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort 80 -Name 'HTTP' -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 80 | Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort 443 -Name 'HTTPS' -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 443| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "mysite" -ReservedIPName "mysiteip" -Location "East US" -VNetName "mysite"
```

Don't know why but it did.  I had tried this before without any luck.